# How to host my asp.net Mvc 3 web application on one PC and access this web application from other PCs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localhost

i have built an asp.net MVc 3 web application on my machine , now i need to host this web application locally to be accessed by four employees in our office. so i need to know the following:-

1. can i host my asp.net mvc web application inside my machine ? and then connect the other four machines into my PC ?
2. is there any link that can help me in implementing similar tasks?
   BR

Answer (score 1):

If you have IIS installed on your machine, you can host your MVC3 app as a website there.  As long as it is the only site bound to port 80, your site should be browsable by other employees in the office at `http://<your computer name>/`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for ur reply, but now how i will physically connect the four PCs to my PC ?

Comment: Are you running on some kind of internal network?  If you are asking about setting up a network/domain, [serverfault.com](http://www.serverfault.com) is a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Setup the website in your IIS.
If Win XP, add file extension in IIS Application settings
Add file extension .* to aspnet_isapi.dll (.NET 4.0)